# Khronos: Primary CMake file

Tags: portability, cmake, khronos

So recently I made a large project of mine open source: [Khronos](https://github.com/syb0rg/Khronos).  I will be dissecting parts of it so that I can have it reviewed more easily here and so that the project as a whole will be improved.  The first part I want to have reviewed is the CMake file involved with kicking off the building process of the project.  Please feel free to tear it apart.

**[CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/syb0rg/Khronos/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
include(ExternalProject)
project(Khronos)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES EP_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/library-build)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=gnu11 -O3")

if (GCC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "4.8")
elsif (GCC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "4.1.2")
    SET (GCC_COMMON_WARNING_FLAGS "-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Winline -Winvalid-pch -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wstack-protector -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum")
    SET (GCC_COMMON_WARNING_FLAGS "${GCC_COMMON_WARNING_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-parameter")
    SET (GCC_CXX_WARNING_FLAGS "-Wctor-dtor-privacy")
else ()
    SET(GCC_COMMON_WARNING_FLAGS "-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Winline -Winvalid-pch -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wstack-protector -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum")
    SET(GCC_COMMON_WARNING_FLAGS "${GCC_COMMON_WARNING_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-parameter")
    SET(GCC_CXX_WARNING_FLAGS "-Wctor-dtor-privacy")
endif ()

# add a target to generate API documentation with Doxygen
find_package(Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    add_custom_target(doc
        ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen" VERBATIM
        )
endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
find_package(Portaudio REQUIRED)
find_package(Flite REQUIRED)
find_package(LibSndFile REQUIRED)
find_package(PortAudio)
if(${PORTAUDIO_FOUND})
else(${PORTAUDIO_FOUND})
    message(STATUS "Could not find PortAudio.  This dependency will be downloaded.")
    ExternalProject_Add(
        PortAudio
        SVN_REPOSITORY "https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/portaudio/portaudio/trunk/"
        SVN_TRUST_CERT 1
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/PortAudio
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/PortAudio/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
        BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
        UPDATE_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
        LOG_UPDATE ON
        LOG_CONFIGURE ON
        LOG_BUILD ON
        LOG_TEST ON
        LOG_INSTALL ON
    )
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(PortAudio source_dir)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(PortAudio binary_dir)
    set(PORTAUDIO_SOURCE_DIR ${source_dir})
    set(PORTAUDIO_BINARY_DIR ${binary_dir})
    set(PORTAUDIO_LIBRARIES ${PORTAUDIO_BINARY_DIR}/lib/.libs/libportaudio.dylib)
    include_directories(${PORTAUDIO_SOURCE_DIR})
    set(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} PortAudio)
endif(${PORTAUDIO_FOUND})

message(STATUS "Could not find parcel.  This dependency will be downloaded.")
ExternalProject_Add(
    parcel
    GIT_REPOSITORY "git://github.com/syb0rg/parcel.git"
    GIT_TAG "c2fd447cd2af552021304e64b6bd66c88c170241"
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/parcel
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    LOG_UPDATE ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
    LOG_TEST ON
    LOG_INSTALL ON
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(parcel source_dir)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(parcel binary_dir)
set(PARCEL_SOURCE_DIR ${source_dir})
set(PARCEL_BINARY_DIR ${binary_dir})
set(PARCEL_LIBRARIES ${PARCEL_BINARY_DIR}/libparcel.a)
set(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} parcel)

find_package(CURL)
if(${CURL_FOUND})
else(${CURL_FOUND})
    message(STATUS "Could not find libcURL.  This dependency will be downloaded.")
    ExternalProject_Add(
        libcurl
        GIT_REPOSITORY "git://github.com/bagder/curl.git"
        GIT_TAG "1b6bc02fb926403f04061721f9159e9887202a96"
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/curl
        PATCH_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/cURL/buildconf
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/cURL/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
        BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
        UPDATE_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
        LOG_UPDATE ON
        LOG_CONFIGURE ON
        LOG_BUILD ON
        LOG_TEST ON
        LOG_INSTALL ON
    )
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(libcurl source_dir)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(libcurl binary_dir)
    set(CURL_SOURCE_DIR ${source_dir})
    set(CURL_BINARY_DIR ${binary_dir})
    set(CURL_LIBRARIES ${CURL_BINARY_DIR}/lib/.libs/libcurl.dylib)
    include_directories(${CURL_SOURCE_DIR})
    set(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} libcurl)
endif(${CURL_FOUND})

find_package(FLAC) # test if FLAC is installed on the system
if(${FLAC_FOUND}) # do something if it is found, maybe tell the user
else(${FLAC_FOUND}) # FLAC isn't installed on the system and needs to be downloaded
    ExternalProject_Add(
    FLAC
    URL "http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/flac/flac-1.3.0.tar.xz"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/flac/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
    BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/flac
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
    )
endif(${FLAC_FOUND})

#find_package(LibOgg)

#find_package(LibVorbis)

find_package(LibSndFile)
if(${LIBSNDFILE_FOUND})
else(${LIBSNDFILE_FOUND})
    ExternalProject_Add(
        LibSndFile
        DEPENDS FLAC libogg libvorbis
        URL "http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.25.tar.gz"
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/LibSndFile/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
        BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/LibSndFile
        UPDATE_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
        LOG_UPDATE ON
        LOG_CONFIGURE ON
        LOG_BUILD ON
        LOG_TEST ON
        LOG_INSTALL ON
    )
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(LibSndFile source_dir)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(LibSndFile binary_dir)
    set(LIBSNDFILE_SOURCE_DIR ${source_dir})
    set(LIBSNDFILE_BINARY_DIR ${binary_dir})
    set(LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARIES ${LIBSNDFILE_BINARY_DIR}/)
    include_directories(${LIBSNDFILE_SOURCE_DIR})
    set(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} LibSndFile)
endif(${LIBSNDFILE_FOUND})

find_package(Flite)

include_directories(src/audio src/web ${PARCEL_SOURCE_DIR})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${PARCEL_LIBRARIES} ${PORTAUDIO_LIBRARIES} ${FLITE_LIBRARIES} ${LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARY} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c)

add_executable(Khronos ${sources})
add_dependencies(Khronos ${DEPENDENCIES})
target_link_libraries(Khronos ${LIBS})
```

Comment: Is there anything that you'd specifically like reviewed? Or just general stuff?

Comment: @EthanBierlein Anything and everything :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm not a CMake user, so this review may be shorter, and mostly focused on style and readability. This questions needs some love though, so I'll do my best.*

---

Why do you have comments in the code below?

```
find_package(FLAC) # test if FLAC is installed on the system
if(${FLAC_FOUND}) # do something if it is found, maybe tell the user
else(${FLAC_FOUND}) # FLAC isn't installed on the system and needs to be downloaded
...
```

And not in other sections similar to the above? Like this:

```
find_package(CURL)
if(${CURL_FOUND})
else(${CURL_FOUND})
...
```

If you really want to add comments to these, then I'd recommend not inlining them, and placing them like this:

```
# Test if FooBar is installed on the system.
# Do something if it is found, and tell the
# user it needs to be downloaded if it isn't
# found on the system.
find_package(FOOBAR)
if(${FOOBAR_FOUND})
else(${FOOBAR_FOUND})
...
```

I find these comments to not really be needed anyways, so I'd just remove them all together.

---

Some part of me find blocks of code like the below particularly difficult to read:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    parcel
    GIT_REPOSITORY "git://github.com/syb0rg/parcel.git"
    GIT_TAG "c2fd447cd2af552021304e64b6bd66c88c170241"
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/parcel
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    LOG_UPDATE ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
    LOG_TEST ON
    LOG_INSTALL ON
)
```

I'd consider possibly aligning values in a fashion similar to this, if CMake allows it:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    parcel
    GIT_REPOSITORY  "git://github.com/syb0rg/parcel.git"
    GIT_TAG         "c2fd447cd2af552021304e64b6bd66c88c170241"
    SOURCE_DIR      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/parcel
    UPDATE_COMMAND  ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD    ON
    LOG_UPDATE      ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE   ON
    LOG_BUILD       ON
    LOG_TEST        ON
    LOG_INSTALL     ON
)
```

Now it's *much* clearer to the reader what each value specifically maps to.

---

You have a couple of indentation issues scattered around various places. For example, this:

```
add_custom_target(doc
    ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen" VERBATIM
    )
```

Should become this:

```
add_custom_target(doc
    ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen" VERBATIM
)
```

And this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
FLAC
URL "http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/flac/flac-1.3.0.tar.xz"
CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/flac/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/flac
UPDATE_COMMAND ""
INSTALL_COMMAND ""
LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
LOG_CONFIGURE ON
LOG_BUILD ON
)
```

Should become this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    FLAC
    URL "http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/flac/flac-1.3.0.tar.xz"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/flac/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
    BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/flac
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
)
```

While these are minor issues, it's still hard to read when things aren't properly indented.

---

That's about all I can really cover, if there's anything else you want me to cover, just mention it in the comments, and I'll see what I can do.